# Implement camera preview in native and use in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-camera, native-code

I want to implement a native android camera preview (using c++) and display this preview on a flutter application.

I couldn't find any direct possible way to do so - up to this point the only solution I could find (which I still am not sure if it will work and think it might be too complex) is the following:

Implement a native stream using ACameraCaptureSession_setRepeatingRequest and ACameraDevice_createCaptureRequest, pass it to Java, and convert it to an android view, and then using Flutter's PlatformView.

As I mentioned, I'm not sure it will work, and even if it does, I wonder if there is some simpler way to do it.